# Query to fetch records from multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, relationships, nosql

I am working on a database in Mongodb. I have a collection, namely 'employees' which stores information about the employees. I have another collection, namely 'jobs' which stores information about jobs. Now each job is divided into many tasks and each task in assigned to 1 or more employees. I am usign Reference to make relationship between these two collections.

This is my document from the collection 'employees'

```
{
   "_id": 1,   --- this is the employee ID
   "Emp_Name": "John",
   "Work_Type" : "Permanent"
   "Gender" : "Male"
}
```

This is my document from the collection 'jobs'

```
{
  "_id" : 1,    --- this is the job ID
  "Job_Title" : "School Building",
  "Job_Status" : "Incomplete",
  "Job_Tasks" : 
     { 
       "task_title" : "Building Design",
       "task_detail" : "Here goes task details",
       "Employees" :
         {
           "_id" : 1,  --- this is the employee ID which refers to employee with ID 1 
         }
      }
   }
```

Now I want a query to show that which task is assigned to which employee. For example, show me the employees name to which the first task is assigned in job.

This is a snapshot from the collection 'Job'. I am using RoboMongo for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show what you want the query result to look like?

Comment: I want a query to show which task is assigned to which employee..for example, in the  job collection, i have only one document and its ID is 1 and for now, this job has only one task which is assigned to the employee whose ID is also 1. The employee ID in the Job collection acts as a foreign key.

Comment: So `Job_Tasks.Employees` could possibly have multiple employees? If so you'll need to make it an array of employee ids.

Comment: Yes. Job_Tasks,Employees can have multiple employees. It stores employee IDs in an array.

Comment: I have added an image or snapshot of the collection Job.